# Action Mailer not working in Dev environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

*I looked at other Action Mailer answers on here and none of the solutions seemed to resolve the issue.*

I am trying to implement the Action Mailer shown [here](https://howilearnedrails.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/setting-up-email-in-a-rails-4-app-with-action-mailer-in-development-and-sendgrid-in-production-using-heroku/), but it is not working for me at all. I am using a FB login to gather the users information, and then using a find_or_create option to update the user.

```
user = User.find_or_create_by(fb_id: profile_hash["id"])
  user.update(sanitized_hash)
  user.save

  log_in user

  redirect_to current_user_profession(user)
```

In the users controller, I am calling on the mail method on the save method. But for some reason it is not sending out the email once a user instance is saved.

```
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)

@image = Image.new

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
    log_in @user
    format.html { redirect_to "/talent", notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

I am sure I have all the coding correct, but for some reason it does not send out a welcome email. From my understanding I am using my personal gmail account credentials, with my username and password, which seemed odd to me, but I did it anyways.

Here is my development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'localhost:3000'}

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: "smtp.gmail.com",
port: 587,
domain: "gmail.com",
authentication: "plain",
enable_starttls_auto: true,
user_name: ENV['GMAIL_USER_NAME'],
password: ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD']
}
```

The actual email to be sent

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hey <%= @user.name  %>,</h1>
    <p>Welcome to the site!</p>
    <p>To login to the site just click on this link <%= @url %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the user_mailer.rb file.

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "support@mystyleblox.com"

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url = 'http://www.mystyleblox.com'
    mail(to:@user.email, subject:'test welcome email')
  end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated, and also if someone could explain the development.rb file and what it needs for the gmail access, is this my personal account, or is this something I had to do separately from my personal account. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "not working"? I'm guessing the email is not being sent. But what kind of error message(s) are you seeing?

Comment: Thats the thing I am not even able to see any errors in my terminal. But yes by not working it is not sending the email to the new user.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate a possible source of the issue, it may well be worth hard-coding your gmail username and password - again, just as a test - so that it's not an issue with the loading of the ENV vars.

I use Rails.application.secrets.domain_name for hiding my super-secret awesome domains but before I get there, I typically use hard-coded values, etc. One thing I noticed between your and my local setup is the domain. My domain is not `gmail.com`; rather, it's the actual domain of my app.

Locally in my app, I have the following which works for my local server sending emails.

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: 'my domain',
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: 'my email address',
  password: 'mypass'
}
# ActionMailer Config
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
# Send email in development mode?
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Just a thought ...

Comment: Ok I will give it a shot. Thanks, and I will let you know if it works

Comment: No problem! Make sure you have `perform_deliveries` set to `true` in your `development.rb` file as well ... kind of matters :)

Comment: Yeah still is not working. Also double checked my passwords in Google but it is still not sending the email to the user once the user is created.

Comment: Yeah I did not have the perform_deliveries in the first trial, once I saw your answer I included it but still does not send the email

Comment: I may have just had a total facepalm moment. Did you restart your Rails server after you changed the development.rb file? It would need to be restarted so that new `perform_deliveries` value (`true`) is picked up.

Comment: I thought that could of been an issue as well, but yes I did restart the app.